# Sorting 2 arrays to get the highest in one and lowest in another

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays. The keys represent the player id in a game (and is the same in both arrays) and the value represents the Ping in one and the score in the other. What I am trying to do is get the Player ID (key) that has the highest ping and the lowest score. I can't get my head around any of the sorts that would do this.

I don't have to use 2 arrays, I just don't know how else to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if player 1 has the highest score (say, 500), but player 2 has the lowest ping (say, 0.1ms)? Which should take precedence?

Comment: Highest ping THEN lowest score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LIVE Demo**: http://codepad.org/46m3mHIH

Arranging this type of architecture would work better...

```
$players = array(
    array(
        "name" => "l337 H4x0r",
        "score" => 10432,
        "ping" => 0.35
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "El Kabooom",
        "score" => 19918,
        "ping" => 0.45
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "Kapop",
        "score" => 10432,
        "ping" => 0.38
    )
);
```

Then you could more efficiently [sort your multi-dimensional array](http://www.firsttube.com/read/sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array-with-php/), and retrieve your `$lowestScore` and `$highestPing` values.

```
$playersScore = subval_sort($players,'score'); 
$lowestScore = $playersScore[0]['score'];

$playersPing = subval_sort($players,'ping'); 
$HighestPing = $playersPing[ count($players)-1 ]['score'];

function subval_sort($a,$subkey) {
    foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
        $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
    }
    asort($b);
    foreach($b as $key=>$val){
        $c[] = $a[$key];
    }
    return $c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I was thinking of using a multi demsional array but didn't know how to sort anything.

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear whether you're looking for two separate sorts, or 1 combined. If separate then the asort() function will sort based on the values while maintaining the correct key=>value association. Just use this against each array.