# Sort a multi-dimensional array using PHP

Tags: php

My array is created like this:

```
$c3_array[$c3_count]["box"] = $box;
$c3_array[$c3_count]["subseries"] = $subseries;
$c3_array[$c3_count]["foldertitle"] = $foldertitle;
$c3_array[$c3_count]["uri"] = $uri;
```

How can I sort the array based on "box" ASC, then based on "foldertitle" ASC?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by based on? Do you want to return box and foldertitle values only?

Comment: I think he means first sort by 'box' ASC, if there is > 1 value of box the same, then sort those by 'foldertitle'....

Comment: No, I want to return all of the values of the array, just now sorted by box values, then preferably sorted by folder titles.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044726/sort-multi-array-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use usort and create your own comparison function. Here is a simple example, that might or might not work, depending on what the actual values in the arrays are, but it should at least give you the idea.

```
function mysort ($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['box'] > $b['box']) return 1;
    if ($a['box'] < $b['box']) return -1;
    if ($a['foldertitle'] > $b['foldertitle']) return 1;
    if ($a['foldertitle'] < $b['foldertitle']) return -1;
    return 0;
}

usort($c3_array, 'mysort');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `array_multisort()` is what you need. Check the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Answer (score 0):

Using [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), as in example 3.

```
$boxes = array();
$foldertitles = array();
foreach($c3_array as $key => $array) {
    $boxes[$key] = $array['box'];
    $foldertitles[$key] = $array['foldertitle'];
}

array_multisort($boxes, SORT_ASC, $foldertitles, SORT_ASC, $c3_array);
```