# how can i sort array by date in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array and i want to sort it in ascending order by date. I tried various answers from this site but none of them is working right. So how can I do this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => 09/01/2017
    [1] => 08/01/2017
    [2] => 07/01/2017
    [3] => 06/01/2017
    [4] => 05/01/2017
    [5] => 04/01/2017
    [6] => 03/01/2017
    [7] => 02/01/2017
    [8] => 01/01/2017
    [9] => 12/12/2016
    [10] => 11/12/2016
    [11] => 10/12/2016
    [12] => 09/12/2016
    [13] => 25/12/2016
    [14] => 24/12/2016
    [15] => 23/12/2016
    [16] => 26/12/2016
    [17] => 28/12/2016
    [18] => 30/12/2016
    [19] => 29/12/2016
    [20] => 22/12/2016
    [21] => 27/12/2016
    [22] => 15/12/2016
    [23] => 16/12/2016
    [24] => 14/12/2016
    [25] => 13/12/2016
    [26] => 17/12/2016
    [27] => 18/12/2016
    [28] => 20/12/2016
    [29] => 19/12/2016
    [30] => 21/12/2016
)
```

I am using PHP. This is what i tried so far. This function doesn't sort as mentioned in all other questions.

```
$data = array listed above;
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if (strtotime($a) == strtotime($b))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return (strtotime($a) < strtotime($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($data, "cmp");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Multi Array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044726/sort-multi-array-in-php)

Comment: This may be duplicate but i can't get it working from other answers.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you post some code you tried but didn't work so we can help you out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you string is `dd/mm/yy` type, cannot directly used by `strtotime` or `date_create`. You can use `DataTime` to create the `datetime`, then use the `datetime` compare operators.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){return DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $a) > DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $b);});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$document_list = array( array );
$document_list= array_map(function($v) {
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($v));
}, $document_list);

function sortByDate($a, $b) {
    return  strtotime($b) - strtotime($a);
}

usort($document_list, "sortByDate");

$document_list= array_map(function($v) {
    return date('m-d-Y', strtotime($v));
}, $document_list);
```

Comment: You don't need to use `array_map`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function desc_date_sort($a, $b){
    $date1ts = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $a);
    $date2ts = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $b);
    return $date1ts === $date2ts ? 0 : ( $date1ts < $date2ts ? 1 : -1 ); 
}
usort($dates_array, 'desc_date_sort');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function cmp($a,$b){
    return strtotime($a['created'])<strtotime($b['created'])?1:-1;
};
// $array pass your array name
uasort($array,'cmp');
```