# using date in if condition in php?

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, date, codeigniter-2

I make a condition like this

```
<?php $todays_date = date("d F Y"); ?> //echo 04 June 2017
<?php $deadline_date = date("d F Y",strtotime($tugas->deadline_tugas));?> //echo 25 May 2017
<?php if ($todays_date < $deadline_date){  <--- I confused in this condition!
 echo "<a class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' href=\"student_tugas/".$tugas->id_tgs."\">Go Activate!</a>";
 }else {
    echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' disabled='disabled'>Oops!</button>";
} ?>
```

> I want this code run when $deadline_date has reached $todays_date and
>   so then the button is "Oops!" but when the $deadline_date has reached
>   $todays_date yet then the button will be show "Go Activate!". As long
>   as $deadline_date has not reach $todays_date and so the button "Go
>   Activate!" will be show.

Could you help me?

Comment: This question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847736/comparing-two-dates

Answer (score 0):

your `if` statement is compare 2 string come from the `date()` function. So it will now be correctly, for example `'June' < 'May'`, but actually not.

Refer to this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41543838/6521116)** for compare the date and the [manual of date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)